# Вставить элемент массива в другой после определенного количества элементов массива

Tags: perl

Добрый день. Как с помощью Perl можно вставить элементы одного массива в другой после определенного количества элементов.

Есть массив

```
@DATA=[1a,2b,3c,4d,5f,6g,7q,8r,...235bgh,1b,2g,3k,4j...];
```

То есть мне не известно, что конкретно содержится в строках, в массиве более 1000к строк.
Мне нужно добавить в этот массив по очереди элементы массива:

```
@DATA2=[xxx,yyy,zzz,...];
```

В котором содержание строк тоже не известно, после каждой 235 строки массива `@DATA`

С помощью splice добавляет сразу все элементы после нужно строки(принципе как и должно быть)

```
open (IN,"<$xxx");
open (OUT, "<$zzz");
 my @DATA=<OUT>;
 my @DATA2=<IN>;
splice @DATA, 234,0,@DATA2;
print dump(\@DATA);
close IN;
close OUT;
```

Может есть другие способы это сделать?

Comment: Sorry, я немного не так задание понял сначала. Тогда вопрос: что делать если элементы первого массива закончились, а во втором ещё остались?

Comment: Они не могут кончится, каждым 235 элементам первого массива соответствует 1 элемент второго.

Comment: Может. Если, например, в первом массиве 470 элементов, а во втором - 10.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна модификация исходного массива:

```
insert_data( \@source_array, \@add_from, 235 );
# ...
sub insert_data
{
    my ( $src, $add, $portion ) = @_;
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @{$add}; $i++ ) {
        splice @{$src}, $portion * ( $i + 1 ) + $i, 0, $add->[$i];
    }
    return $src;
}
```